# PageViewController: SetViewController Crashes my App

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, crash

When I run my app, I notice that the `setViewController` method causes a memory link and crashes my app.I have worked on this issue for hours, and have tried looking on the web, and found one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973822/3757370), which mentioned putting my `setViewController` method in the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)` but that terminates the app, and I get the following error in the console:

> 2015-12-26 19:41:55.596 Harish Yerra[4663:132796] XPC connection interrupted
>   2015-12-26 19:41:55.596 Harish Yerra[4663:132797] Terminating since there is no system app.

The iPhone than fully restarts and goes back to the home screen.

I have tried commenting out the `setViewController` method, and my app loads the first page of the Page View Controller fine, and then when I scroll to the next page it crashes again with the following error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_UIQueuingScrollView _replaceViews:updatingContents:adjustContentInsets:animated:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/_UIQueuingScrollView.m:377
>   2015-12-26 19:31:55.058 Harish Yerra[4381:123817] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [views count] == 3'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e411e65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001105b0deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e411cca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x000000010ea824de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
>       4   UIKit                               0x000000010f8d5575 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _replaceViews:updatingContents:adjustContentInsets:animated:] + 289
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010f8d949d -[_UIQueuingScrollView _didScrollWithAnimation:force:] + 1350
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010f8d4701 -[_UIQueuingScrollView layoutSubviews] + 176
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010f1444a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
>       8   QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef4959a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
>       9   QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef3de70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
>       10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef3dcee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>       11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef32475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
>       12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef5fc0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
>       13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef6e9f4 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 576
>       14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e371c84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e371831 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e333241 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e332828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112219ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       19  UIKit                               0x000000010f08d610 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       20  Harish Yerra                        0x000000010d813efd main + 109
>       21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001115f092d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb).

I will provide the code for my `viewDidLoad`, but if you need the code for the entire PageViewControllerDataSource, just let me know and I will provide it. Thanks so much for your help.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.pageViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    let initialViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! HarishIntroduction
    let viewController = NSArray(object: initialViewController)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewController as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-100)
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Comment: You're running that on a real device? :O

Comment: The same thing happens when running in real device or on the simulator.

Comment: Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com. Under no circumstances should your app crash the system!

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [views count] == 3' says that you need 3 views. So you update all your UI on the main thread?

Comment: @HAS I think I found the issue to my app, but even I was confused because the whole system crashed and my iPhone restarted even when running on a real device. I started running my app in the simulator because I was scared I would break the phone. I will file a bug report though just so Apple knows that there is some code which could potentially crash the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks so much for your help everybody. However, I think I found what my problem was. My first error was not putting the `setViewControllers` method in `dispatch_get_main_queue()`. Also, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734673/uipageviewcontroller-with-different-viewcontrollers-right-way) helped me out a lot. It basically told me to use `if` statements on the `viewController.isKindOfClass` method to determine which view to correctly navigate to in the dataSource methods of the `pageViewController` `beforeViewController`, and `afterViewController` methods.

I really hope this post helps anybody else who might have the same issue as me. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want create a UIPageViewController? You can find best details in your Xcode! Just click the button " Page Based Application " instead of the " Single View Application "! Apple already been provided latest changes in Xcode 7.2 with huge line of codes! Good luck!

Comment: Ya, but only part of my app is a PageViewController not all of it. Also, I have created a large portion of my app so it would be a pain to start over. However, is it possible to import an Xcode Project into another Xcode Project?

Comment: @Harish you can select page based application in another project  & copy & paste that view controller into your current project

Comment: @AjinkyaPatil Ok, I will try that, but the only issue is I have the majority of the whole PageViewController setup done. As a result, I really want to try to fix the issue, and if there is no solution to fixing the issue I will use the template that Apple has provided.